# Count word/pos from file

Tags: python, dictionary

I've almost solved an exercise from my python lectures. I've been asked to write a program that counts how often each word occurs in a file, and how often it has been tagged with which POS.
The counts should be written to a new file, which is also given on the command line.

For instance,

```
python3 wordcount-pos.py wsj00-pos.txt counts-wsj00-pos.txt
```

should produce a output like this:

```
   Mortimer 1   NNP 1

   foul 1   JJ  1

   ...

   reported 16  VBN 7   VBD 9

   ...

   before   26  RB  6   IN  20

   ...

   allow    4   VB  2   VBP 2
```

My code produces an output such as:

```
   Mortimer 1   {NNP:   1}

   foul 1   {JJ: 1}

   ...

   reported 2   {VBN:   7   VBD:    9}

   ...

   before   2   {RB:    6   IN: 20}

   ...

   allow    2   {VB:    2   VBP:    2}
```

It doesn't print the occurrences of "word" in my dictionary

Here it is my code:

```
import sys
from collections import defaultdict


def main():
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print('Usage: python poscount.py <input file>', file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(1)

    input_filename = sys.argv[1]
    output_filename = sys.argv[2]
    # your code
    freq = defaultdict(list)
    with open(input_filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            # skip empty lines
            if line.strip() != '':
                #  split a word/pos pair into two separate strings
                word, pos = line.strip().rsplit("/", 1)
                # add word and list of pos as k, v into "freq" dictionary
                freq[word].append(pos)

    for k, v in freq.items():
        D = defaultdict(list)
        for i, item in enumerate(v):
            D[item].append(i)
        D = {k: len(v) for k, v in D.items()}
        # Output file
        with open(output_filename, "a") as f:
            print(k + "\t" + str(len(D.items())) + "\t" + str(D), file=f)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

file from where extract the data: https://paste.elnota.space/nezemivaku.sql

Partial content of the file:

Pierre/NNP

Vinken/NNP

,/,

61/CD

years/NNS

old/JJ

,/,

will/MD

join/VB

the/DT

board/NN

as/IN

a/DT

nonexecutive/JJ

director/NN

Nov./NNP

29/CD

./.

Mr./NNP
 Vinken/NNP

is/VBZ

chairman/NN

Comment: What do you mean by `how often it has been tagged with which POS.`

Comment: So the error is that it should print e.g. `reported 16`, and instead it's printing `reported  2`?

Comment: That's correct @JohnGordon

Comment: If you could provide a sample input and output that would help us understand what you are trying to solve.

Comment: I attached a hastebin link to the question with the input

Comment: The hastebin link does not work with automated tools such as `wget`.

Comment: here it is: https://send.firefox.com/download/93891817cea23cf4/#Ta0Yl0GpWTE3MvAJgSnyiw

Comment: That link also does not appear to work with `wget`.  Can you include the first ten lines of the file in your post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will solve your problem

```
print(k + "\t" + str(sum(D.values())) + "\t" + str(D), file=f)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, although it gives "KeyError: `Pierre`"

Comment: using D[k], gave you a keyError, could you print the content of D?

Comment: If I print D, I get a dictionary of "pos" values with their occurrences (see original post)

Comment: I think this will work
print(k + "\t" + str(sum(D.values())) + "\t" + str(D), file=f)